# (MODx) How to set the default value of a resource setting?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

In the latest MODx (2.3.1) I'd like to make the 'Container' checkbox (system key *isfolder*) for a document resource checked by default.
How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modx you can set a default field value in many ways. Possible via a plugin, but you can do it easy through form-customization ( http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/customizing-the-manager/form-customization-sets )

```
1. Go to Security --> Form Customization.
2. Create new profile and go edit him.
3. Inside profile create new "Set Rules" on "create resource" action, 
   live template blank if you do not have to limit on it.
4. Edit new set of rules and set inside property "isfolder" to 1.
5. Save and check how it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the system "you can't", what you will have to do is create a plugin that fires on one of the document save events, it's going to be a little complicated to implement but there is a discussion and some code examples here for you to follow.

http://forums.modx.com/thread/81774/automatically-tick-container-box-when-subpage